# SSRS - Reports Manager displaying Http500 cannot be displayed

Tags: reporting-services

SSRS - Reports Manager displaying Http500 cannot be displayed

localhost/Reports shoes http 500, page cannot be displayed

localhost/ReportManager shows the old school look of directory listing via text, like an old ftp site you view through your browser.  I can browse to my report, run, and view it.  It just looks like the nice frame work around the report manager is not displaying.

Any ideas?  Is there any easy way to revert all my settings and configs?  I was goofing around trying to set the maxhttpRequest="more than 4mbs" in the web.config file.  I probably mucked it all up.  I set it back, but still no solution.

Comment: Here is the error i get in my log file: appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!21e4!07/17/2013-09:22:17:: e ERROR: AppDomain ReportManager_MSSQLSERVER_0 failed to start. Error: '”' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 19, position 35.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are seeing on URL `http://localhost/ReportManager` is actually the *Report Server* directories, not the Report Manager web application. The report server URL is normally set up on `http://localhost/reportserver` so it sounds like your report server has been configured in an unusual way. The best thing to do if you are able is to run the Reporting Services Configuration Manager tool for the report server you are connecting to and check the values configured for:

Web Service URL ( this is the normally set up as /reportserver but it sounds like you are seeing it on /reportmanager)

Report Manager URL (this is the URL you are looking for to view the reports in the Report Manager application)

Comment: I'm getting "Page can't be Displayed" in both instances now =(

Comment: Did you check the URLs for Web Service and Report Manager in Reporting Services Configuration Manager as I suggested? What was displayed there?

Answer (score -1):

Adding the SSRS host to the trusted site list in my browser fixed this.